# How do I return a value from a Java function?

Tags: java, return-value

I am trying to get the following program to work:

```
public class funWithNumbers {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int ten = 10;
    int subend = 7;
    int result = ten - subend;
    int success = 0;
    int trials = 750;
    for (int i=0; i<trials; i++) {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 200;
        randomNumber++;
        int randNum = (int) randomNumber;
        int mystery = randNum;
        returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);
    }
    int accuracy = (success / trials) * 100;
    System.out.println("Trials Run: " + trials);
    System.out.println("We can say that the number " + result + " indeed equals " + result + " with " + accuracy + "% accuracy.");
}
public static int returnTen(int mystery, int subend, int result, int success) {
    int original = mystery;
    mystery = mystery + mystery;
    mystery = mystery * 5;
    mystery = mystery / original;
    mystery = mystery - subend;
    if (mystery == result) {
        success++;
    }
    return success;
}
}
```

Everything in this program works except that last statement (`return success`). For whatever reason, I cannot return the value from the `returnTen` function back to the main program. I tried debugging the program using `System.out.println()` statements along the way (not included above) and within the `returnTen` function itself, the `success` variable is successfully incremented. But I cannot get that to pass back to the main function.

What should happen: You'll notice the function is basically a common number trick. The end result of `mystery` should be 3 (which is what result is). Therefore, `success` should always be incremented every time the function runs. Which means that accuracy should be 100%, and the statement printed out should read `We can say that the number 3 indeed equals 3 with 100% accuracy`

What is happening: The end statement currently prints `We can say that the number 3 indeed equals 3 with 0% accuracy` which is obviously not true - `success` is not being passed back and therefore, accuracy is being calculated as 0%.

**EDIT:** Changing `returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);` to `success = returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);` changes the end statement from 0% to 25000%.
**UPDATE:** Fixed the problem - `success =` needed to be added and I had to change `success / result` to `success / trials` - oops!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Pretty much this question could be the dupe, i fell like you are using it as it would pass a reference to the `int`'s, in this case `success`, but you need to store it somewhere as `success = returnTen(...)`

Comment: Your edit should probably be a new question, since it likely identifies a symptom from a different problem.

Comment: I agree with Kevin, `returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);` this call clearly forget to store the return value so this expect that the `success` pass will be change after the call.

Comment: And before creating a new question, since this is totaly different, this probably need to be investigate a bit from your part ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your returnTen() function is returning the value, but your code is not using that value.  To use the return value, the line:

```
returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);
```

should be:

```
success = returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that `return success;` isn't working (it is), it's that you're not *using* the return value. When you call the function, you need to *use* the return value:

```
    success = returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of a return a value from a function you must assign it to a variable or use it as a test condition, etc.

```
if(returnTen(mystery, subend, result, success) > 0){
    System.out.println("returnTen returned an int value");
}
```

Currently your code is discarding the return value since it is not assigned to anything.